# How to find first IN and last OUT for a particular column?

Tags: hive, partition-by

I have a table having a column event. It has data like IN and OUT.

Now I need to create two columns having the time of the first IN for a particular ID and the last OUT for the same ID.

I need to use partition by window function with lead and lag.

How can I do this?

Any help would be great!

I have to do this in HIVE!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you also have some date column (lets call it `dt`).
To get first IN and last OUT for all the IDs you need to do something like this :

```
select 
  id,
  min(case when event='IN' then dt end) first_in, 
  max(case when event='OUT' then dt end) last_out
from table
group by id
```

Comment: Hi.. thank you so much for your input.. If I use this query there will be null values.. since not all id will have IN & OUT values.. Can you tell me how I can remove those null values?

Comment: you can either use `coalesce` you put something other than null there : `coalesce(max(case...),'SOMETHING')` or remove those lines in `having` : `having max(case..) is not null`

Comment: for some reason this Having is not working... I will give you the scenario.. I need to find the first IN for a particular ID and the last OUT for the same of the same session and not the last OUT of the day.. does this make sense?